# Input onChange w/ React & TypeScript errors: jsx no-lambda no-bind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, tslint

I am creating a simple task demo and making the taskNameInput component. You can see a couple ways I've tried to approach this, but I keep getting errors. How to  for React with Typescript?

You can see my repo for my tsconfig.json and tslint.json: https://github.com/Falieson/react15-meteor1.5 , I'm using `tslint-react` comes with `jsx-no-lambda` and `jsx-no-bind`

**triggers jsx-no-bind error**

```
public renderTaskInput(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleNewTaskName.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**triggers jsx-no-lambda error**

```
 public renderTaskInput(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => this.handleNewTaskName(e)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

My previous commit was a Counter example. You can see my CounterComponent's call to bind doesn't cause a `jsx-no-bind` error and satisfies the jsx-no-lambda rule.

```
return (
  <button onClick={this.handleChangeValue.bind(this, decrement)}>
    {decrement ? 'Decrease' : 'Increase'}
  </button>
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the difference in how handleNewTaskName is instantiated with name=()=>{} instead of just name() {}

Bind the method in the constructor, or use the es7 class syntax. Here's the solution:

```
  public handleNewTaskName = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
  this.setState({newTaskTitle: e.currentTarget.value})
 }
 public renderTaskInput(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder='New Task Name'
          name='app-tasks-inputTaskName'
          onChange={this.handleNewTaskName}
        />
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: I would love to see a solution that somehow leveraged TypeScript's ability to infer the event type w/o typing out `React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, but I can't come up with it myself.